# Easy way to add a 'None' option to spinner?

Tags: android

So right now I have a Spinner where you select from a list of ingredients. It pulls the list from a database and by default, the first list in the spinner if the first item in the db. The issue is, once the user selects an item in the spinner, there is no way to then unselect that item. The user can select a different item, but they cant select the entire spinner, lets say, Sauce, to nothing at all.

Is there a way to add a 'None' item in the spinner, other than have to add a 'None' ingredient to my database with Null or 0 values?

Comment: How are you setting the data to Spinner, some code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't include any source  Check this out: It should help

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayList<String> yourIngredients = new ArrayList<String>();
//GET ALL INGREDIENTS
//yourIngredients.add(INGREDIENT)
//FINALLY
yourIngredients.add("NONE");
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, yourIngredients.toArray());
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: With mine I made sure that my "empty" spinner was at 0 so it would be the default, so if the user doesn't touch the spinner it's going to be the blank one on the spinner.